# Date comparison using Hibernate Criteria API

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

**Environment :**
Hibernate 4 
Tomcat 6

**Issue :**

I have a column in MySQL database with DATETIME type (abhishekDate is the column name).
I want to compare the user supplied date with this DATETIME column.

But the comparison **should NOT INCLUDE** the time part of the DATETIME column. 
The comparison should be based on **DATE part only.**

Since the query is dynamic , I am using Criteria API. 
But I am not able to achieve the same using Criteria API.
I have tried below code but its not working.

Can you please help on how to write this query ?

Am I using correct approach for the same ?

The exception I am getting is :

```
Mar 08, 2016 9:26:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'abhishekDate' in 'where clause'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
```

But abhishekDate is present in User class (or table)

**Code  :**

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(User.class);
Conjunction and = Restrictions.conjunction();

and.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("year(abhishekDate) = ? ",abhishekDate,org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes.DATE));
and.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("month(abhishekDate) = ? ",abhishekDate,org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes.DATE));
and.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("day(abhishekDate) = ? ",abhishekDate,org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes.DATE));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried another way and it is working for me . I check the date in my table is between the user date and user date plus one day as follow.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(userDate);
cr.add(Restrictions.ge("yourDate", cal.getTime()));
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
cr.add(Restrictions.le("yourDate", cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: should second condition be Restrictions.lt("yourDate", cal.getTime())