# How to compare dates in Criteria API

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, criteria-api

I need to to select data with statement where i compare dates. The SQL request looks like that:

```sql
select c.candidate_id
from candidate c
         left join experience e on c.candidate_id = e.candidate_id
group by c.candidate_id
having (sum(datediff(e.end_working_date, e.start_working_date)) > 365)
   and (sum(datediff(e.end_working_date, e.start_working_date)) <= (365 * 3));
```

But i don't know how to write this code with help Criteria API. I can't to map `java.util.Date` to sql `timestamp` SQL function and i getting NPE.
My object `Experience`

```
public class ExperienceEntity {
   ...
   @Column(name = "start_working_date")
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   private Date startWorkingDate;

   @Column(name = "end_working_date")
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   private Date endWorkingDate;
   ...
}
```

And my request in Criteria API

```
 Expression<Date> endWorkingDate = experienceRoot.get("endWorkingDate");
 Expression<Date> startWorkingDate = experienceRoot.get("startWorkingDate");
 Expression<Integer> dateDiffFunc = builder.function("datediff", Integer.class, endWorkingDate, startWorkingDate);
 select.groupBy(root.get("candidateId"));

 select.having(builder.and(
                            builder.gt(builder.sum(dateDiffFunc), 365),
                            builder.le(builder.sum(dateDiffFunc), 365 * 3)
                    ));
```

`datediff` is a custom function for getting days when subtracting `endWorkingDate` and `startWorkingDate`

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872198/date-comparison-using-hibernate-criteria-api

Comment: Nope, it's not my case